# Unsupported method error

Tags: php, ruby

I am trying to make a contact form using php, but I constantly get an error saying

"Method Not Allowed

unsupported method `POST'.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08) at localhost:2323
"
here's the form tag I have used:

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
```

It may be the webserver I'm using. I remember this working on a computer that was running Windows on it, but now that I'm on a Mac it seems to not work. On Windows I was using a USBwebserver to use php, the name of which was simply USBWebserver, but it doesnt work with Macs. Therefore, I have used a different webserver called "Pinky-1.0", and now I am stil getting errors in my code that used to work

Comment: Are you trying to run Ruby code, or are you trying to run PHP? WEBrick is a Ruby server for Ruby only.

Comment: i was trying to run php. i googled "usbwebserver for mac" and this came up so i used it

Comment: How about ye-olde [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/)?

Comment: i dont have install rights, which is why im looking for a usbwebserver

Comment: It's going to be very hard to do any software development when you don't have sufficient privileges to do your job. You may want to get a small VPS and run PHP there, remotely, as an alternative. I do not know how to use USBWebserver, and after look at the documentation, I'm not sure it's the best choice out there.

Comment: Go with `VirualBox`.

Comment: @mudasobwa All of these things are irrelevant if no software can be installed.

Comment: I am not an expert in macos, but I bet there is a way to run peinstalled `VirtualBox` from an USB stick.

Comment: @tadman its not my job, im a student. this wasnt an issue when i used Windows because i could use a web server off a usb drive. it was like basically hosting my own website off my computer for development purposes. now that im using a Mac its become harder. mudasobwa i will try that, thanks

Comment: OS X is actually significantly easier to do web development work on, most of the UNIX tools work natively and many of the scripting languages prefer a POSIX shell by default. The real problem here is not being able to install software. That makes doing *any* sort of software development quite difficult and running software off of a USB drive is just dodging the issue. What about installing a better code editor? Or a proper web server? If this is a shared computer, you may want to get something like a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) and use it as a development server.